# How does anything listen to tf2? What are the transform_listener_impl nodes?

Tags: ros2, rviz, tf2

I have been trying to understand various robotic setups and I have noticed that RViz works even though it has absolutely no connection to TF - as seen in node subscriptions in `ros2 node info` and `rqt_graph` (no nodes or topics are hidden).

See the attached graph from [TF2 tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Intermediate/Tf2/Introduction-To-Tf2.html). The only subscriber of /tf is some obscure /transform_listener_impl_xxxxx node that only publishes to logs. It is the same in any other setup I try. So how does anything listen to TF / what is that obscure node / where is the problem?

(ros2 humble on ubuntu 22.04)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Its an internal node to TF2 listener that deals with the TF data so that if your server's node is being blocked by a service/action/subscription/timer/etc callback that your TF data is still getting processed in a timely manner and isn't being blocked. If you're aware  enough to control your own data flow so you know this is not going to be an issue, you can disable this `Impl` node by using the constructor API which provides the `Node` next to the `buffer`.

Comment: I see, thank you.So that node is actually inside RViz? Is there any way to see that? I my real case there are 4 such nodes and I don't know where they belong.